# How to select a list item only when hovering on the text using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create a list item in an unordered list at runtime as follows:

```
// Javascript code
var items = document.getElementById("list");

var item = document.createElement("li");
item.className = "ItemClass";
item.innerHTML = "Item";
items.appendChild(item);

document.getElementById('list').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            if ('LI' != event.target.tagName) return;
            // Call a javascript function here
        }, false);

// Css Code

#list 
{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #069;
}

#list ul
{
    list-style:none;
}

#list ul li 
{
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.ItemClass:link
{
    color: #069;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ItemClass:visited
{
    color: #069;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ItemClass:hover
{
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I would like to be able to format the list so that an item can only be selected/highlighted when the text is directly hovered over, not when hovering over white space etc. beside it. Currently it can be selected and the javascript event is fired even when not directly hovered. As I am making a single app application I do not want the page to refresh and therefore I don't think I could use `a href.`How can I fix this, thanks!

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle ???

Comment: What do you mean "directly" hovered? Either you clicked the element or you didn't. Do you only want the actual text of the element to be clickable?

Comment: *" Currently it can be selected and the javascript event is fired even when not directly hovered."* - can you elaborate this part? what do you mean it can be selected? so it should be non-selectable? by not directly hovered you mean by hovering parent elements?

Comment: @Robban Yes, currently it is hightlighted and can be clicked even when the mouse pointer is at the far right hand side of the screen. I want it so that I can only click it when the text in the list is directly hovered and clicked on, not the white space beside it

Comment: @const_ref Then your LI element probably takes up more space than you are aware of. Try adding a background-color to the LI to see exactly how big the element is and use CSS to style it to the appropriate size.

Comment: Can you post the html as well, or a demo?

Comment: @const_ref the answer by dfsq below should solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `UL` element is block level element. It means that it takes as much horizontal space as it can. You either make it `inline-block` of set some specific width (probably better option, but it depends on your case):

```
ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4ckvLrx5/1/

Answer (score 0):

try using a tag inside the list item and prevent default action

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault